Can "Domain Restricted Sharing" Org Policy in GCP work with cloud functions accepting allUsers?
If a project has or inherits a Domain Restricted Sharing org policy, It appears this prevents adding the cloudfunction invoker role to allUsers or allAuthenticatedUsers?
If it's possible to add allUsers to the policy as an allowed domain, what would be the syntax for doing that?
Or is it necessary to override the policy for that project and allow any domain?
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member" "cloud_function_invoker_before_create" {
  project        = <PROJ_ID>
  region         = <REGION>
  cloud_function = name
  role           = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member         = "allUsers"
}

Results in error
Error applying IAM policy for cloudfunctions cloudfunction "projects/<PROJ_ID>/locations/<REGION>/functions/firebaseAuthBeforeCreate": Error setting IAM policy for cloudfunctions cloudfunction googleapi: Error 400: One or more users named in the policy do not belong to a permitted customer.

"violations": [
       {
         "description": "User allUsers is not in permitted organization.",
         "subject": "orgpolicy:,<PROJECT_ID>/<REGION>/firebaseAuthBeforeCreate?configvalue=allUsers",
         "type": "constraints/iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains"
       }


I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided information has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further

From this official GCP document you can find note :

You can't grant roles to allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers at the project level

From this official GCP document, you can find a similar issue and workaround also :

The Cloud Resource Manager API setIamPolicy method overwrites the existing IAM policy and not just appends to it. When writing the IAM policy from scratch with the iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains constraint enabled, the constraint will block the operation if any of the principals don't belong to a safelisted Customer ID.

DRS restricts access to your organization, you can't directly use allUsers or allAuthenticatedUsers with Cloud Functions if DRS is enabled.
EDIT 1:
You cannot directly add allUsers or allAuthenticatedUsers to the allowed domains of a Domain Restricted Sharing policy for a Cloud Function.
You can use IAM for a Cloud Function:
1.Create a service account: Go to the IAM console and create a service account.
2.Grant the "Cloud Functions Invoker" role to the service account: This allows the service account to invoke your Cloud Function.
3.Use the service account's credentials: Provide the service account's credentials (key file or token) to any application that needs to call your function.

Thanks for this answer. The references are useful. I am not trying to set the permissions at project level but on an individual cloud function resource. Is it possible to add allUsers to the allowed domains of a DRS policy?

Please have a look at EDIT 1 section in the answer, which may help to resolve your issue.

Thanks for the EDIT. Do you have a reference? If true, I will have to disable DRS to grant allUsers the invoker role. The cloud blocking function is vetting user accounts before authenticating them. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=1st.

Take a look at this official GCP docs on Authorize access with IAM and Authenticate for invocation. You can enable access to a function by adding principals and granting roles. Select the function then click permissions. Click Add principals then enter the identity (user or service account) that needs access to your function. Select the role and save.
